# "Leider, leider, sogt Beschneider"

Tags: idiom, bavarian, joke

I walked past a chess game in Munich, where someone had just played a very bad move. An old gentleman exclaimed:

> Leider, leider, sogt Beschneider.

It's probable that I misheard a bit.

I suppose it's a "joke" meant to extend "leider", but I can't make any sense out of it. What does it mean?

Answer (score 14):

The full phrase is

> „Leider, leider sagt der Schneider, macht der Schuster keine Kleider.”

and is a simple rhyme meant to gently/jokingly tell you that you can't have everything you want/just the way you want it. A simple translation is "Unfortunately, says the tailor, the shoemaker doesn't make clothes," but it loses all rhythm and rhyme in the translation, and therefore all its charm.

Either you misheard the "Beschneider", or the joker was turning it into a far cruder joke by turning the tailor into a performer of circumcisions. "Leider, leider, sagt der Beschneider" is still kind of funny in a "things you don't want to hear from someone performing delicate surgery on important parts of the male anatomy" sort of way, so if you heard that from the guy who made the very bad chess move, it may have been a joking way of saying "Oops, I just messed up really badly!"

But that's quite far from the original version of the rhyme, and I suspect you simply misheard.

Comment: Also, unless the old guy was not a native speaker, the omission of an article is *very* unlikely. Bavarian needs a "der" (or rather a "da":)) between Verb and Subject.

Comment: I am certain that what he heard was “sagt der Schneider” as my mother used that little phrase on us a lot growing up in Germany, even though she was Austrian  hilarious, but no circumcision involved in this saying

Answer (score 0):

"Beschneider" is the man who performs (male) circumcision.

"sogt" is Bavarian pronunciation for "sagt", i.e. "says".

I guess this is part of a joke, but since I don't know the joke
I can only assume the "Beschneider" is apologizing for cutting off a bit too much.

Comment: I'm quite sure that's all he said. I was hoping that it's part of a common joke/saying that would have be recognisable to listeners.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Cass already said:

It is very common when playing blitz chess (5 minutes per game or less) to utter a constant stream of trash-talk, usually in such a way that the spoken nonsense somehow comments on what is going on on the board. The trash-talker will try to come across as educated (though not necessarily chess-wise) as possible.

For instance, there was a guy I knew in a Café who now and then said, when the opponent made a move:

> Was ists mit dem? Was kann er meinen?

People in the know recognized that as a quote from Schillers ballad "Die Kraniche des Ibykus" (or, as they inadvertantly would call it, "Die Ibiche des Kranikus"), which continues:

> Was ists mit diesem *Kranichzug*?

There is also a common phrase "Sie wissen wohl nicht, wer ich bin" (*Don't you know who I am?*. I once heard - tightening the "nonsense-screw" even one revolution further - "Glauben sie ja nicht, wer ich bin!" (*Don't you believe who I am!*)

Also from Schiller (Piccolomini) and usually said in a situation where a bad decision before continues to be responsible for a bad position without expectations of amelioration:

> Das eben ist der Fluch der bösen Tat,
> Daß sie, fortzeugend, immer Böses muß gebären.

or, when defending against a move the opponent has to make anyway, again Schiller (Wilhelm Tell):

> Durch diese hohle Gasse muß er kommen.

There are no real rules for "good trash-talk" but it usually has to be:

- witty
- show off your education (or lack thereof of your opponent)
- comment indirectly the situation on the board.

The goal is reached when the audience watching the game laughs rapturously. Schiller is an especially thankful object of alienation because his lyrics are so full of their own importance that taking them down a notch immediately creates a humourous effect.

Also this (after a series of exchanges advantegous to one side):

> Er zählt die Häupter seiner Lieben
> und findet anstatt sechse sieben!

Insinuating that some "friend" has helped with the procreation task.

The original is from "Die Glocke": "er zählt die Häupter seiner Lieben und sieh, ihm fehlt kein liebes Haupt" (*he counts his beloved ones and see, none is missing*).

Here is a last example accompanying a move with the queen:

> Auf in den Kampf, die Schwiegermutter naht,
> siegesgewiss klappert ihr Gebiß.

The original is the from the german version of the opera "Carmen" (G. Bizet) and reads:

> Auf in den Kampf, Torero,
> siegesbewußt, stolzgeschwellte Brust.

(*Into the fray, Torero, conscious of your [imminent] victory, breast swollen with pride*) whereas the made-over version is: *into the fray, the mother-in-law nears, sure of her victory rattles her denture*. The "mother-in-law" is a reference to the queen, obviously.